# Sections appear BEFORE the abstract, but they should not. How to solve this?

Tags: formatting

I have got a weird problem. I use a template of a publishing journal (it's a must, to publish in the journals). Using it, the "sections" appear before the "abstract". Strange enough, this problem does not appear if you delete the "\begin{aug} ... \end{aug}" part, but as said it's obligatory prescribed by the journal. How to get the correct order? First abstract, sections thereafter?

The link for the package for the document class is here:
https://vtex-soft.github.io/texsupport.ims-aop/

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[aop,preprint]{imsart}

%% Packages
\RequirePackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{sample title}

\begin{aug}

\author[A]{\fnms{Peter} \snm{Pan}\ead[label=e1]{peter.pan@gmx.de}}

\address[A]{ \printead{e1}}

\end{aug}

\begin{abstract}
ABSTRACT. This is a test abstract. Unfortunately, the sections appear before the abstract. Why is that so?
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
This section should appear after the abstract, but it doesnt. Why?



\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably provide a link for that document class.

Answer (score 1):

The `frontmatter` environment should only contain what's supposed to be in the header of the document. The main text of the document should go *after* `\end{frontmatter}`.

```latex
\documentclass[aop,preprint]{imsart}

%% Packages
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{sample title}

\begin{aug}

\author[A]{\fnms{Peter} \snm{Pan}\ead[label=e1]{peter.pan@gmx.de}}

\address[A]{ \printead{e1}}

\end{aug}

\begin{abstract}
ABSTRACT. This is a test abstract. the sections is after the abstract.
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
This section should appear after the abstract, but it doesnt. Why?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx a lot for the "front matter" hint, that's the solution. It worked!!